# What is the correct way to compose Ramda lenses?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, lenses

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this pipeline. Given an array of students, I want to map over them, adding a new property (`icon`) based on the value of an existing property (`grade`). I've broken the problem down into smaller parts by ignoring the mapping part for now and focusing on each individual problem.

**Conditional**

For this I decided to use `R.cond`

**Getter and Setter**

I'm utilizing lenses for this

**Full Code**

```
const student = {
    "studentName" : "Nancy",
    "grade": "junior",
}

const gradeLens = R.lensProp('grade')
const iconLens = R.lensProp('icon')

const findCondition = R.cond([
  [ R.equals('sophomore'), R.always('bath') ],
  [ R.equals('junior'), R.always('envelope-open') ],
  [ R.equals('senior'), R.always('microchip') ]
])

//Compose the functions together
const setStudentIcon = R.compose(R.set(iconLens), findCondition, R.view(gradeLens))
```

`R.set` expects 3 parameters, which means this function has to be invoked like so:

`setStudentIcon(student)(student)`

I don't know much about functional programming just yet, but this doesn't seem like the correct way to compose lenses.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this:

```
const setStudentIcon = R.chain(
  R.compose(R.set(iconLens), findCondition), 
  R.view(gradeLens)
);

setStudentIcon(student);
//=> {grade: 'junior', icon: 'envelope-open', studentName: 'Nancy'}
```

This takes advantage of how [`chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) works on functions, namely that `chain(f, g)(x) //=> f(g(x), x)`.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20student%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22studentName%22%20%3A%20%22Nancy%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22grade%22%3A%20%22junior%22%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20gradeLens%20%3D%20R.lensProp%28%27grade%27%29%0Aconst%20iconLens%20%3D%20R.lensProp%28%27icon%27%29%0A%0Aconst%20findCondition%20%3D%20R.cond%28%5B%0A%20%20%5B%20R.equals%28%27sophomore%27%29%2C%20R.always%28%27bath%27%29%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5B%20R.equals%28%27junior%27%29%2C%20R.always%28%27envelope-open%27%29%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5B%20R.equals%28%27senior%27%29%2C%20R.always%28%27microchip%27%29%20%5D%0A%5D%29%0A%0A%2F%2FCompose%20the%20functions%20together%0A%2F%2F%20const%20setStudentIcon%20%3D%20R.compose%28R.set%28iconLens%29%2C%20findCondition%2C%20R.view%28gradeLens%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20setStudentIcon%20%3D%20chain%28compose%28set%28iconLens%29%2C%20findCondition%29%2C%20view%28gradeLens%29%29%3B%0A%0AsetStudentIcon%28student%29)**.